# how to pass parse json value through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to get the JSON object from a JSON outputted string from a Rails app. Currently in JavaScript I'm doing:

```
data = "<%= @chromosomes%>";
```

However, since there are quotes at the beginning and end of the JSON object, it is not being rendered as a JSON object. Instead it is doing something like

```
data = "[{"name"=>"YHet","organism_id"=>"4ea9b90e859723d3f7000037"}]"
```

Is there a way that I can remove the beginning and end quotes so that the object is treated as an array instead of a string?

Comment: What type is chromosomes? Is it a raw string (and if so, why)? Does it come from to_json? Other?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse `string` into `JSON` object.

```
data = JSON.parse('<%= @chromosomes%>');
```

Comment: Not safe for `'` or `</script` etc. (There has to be some 'universal' solution..)

Answer (score 1):

Use html_safe in the view, no quotes:

```
<script>
  data = <%= @chromosomes.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

Comment: Can potentially lead to problems with escaping (or lack of), same as with the other current answers.

Comment: how? in the question, it says, JSON outputted string, so, I am expecting in controller he is using @chromosomes.to_json

Comment: Assumptions are assumptions .. I asked the OP for clarification. In any case it would still fail on `</script`. As with all my comments I am trying to elicit some One True For All Time approach.

Answer (score 1):

**data = '<%= @chromosomes%>';
var result = JSON.parse(data);**

if you do console.log(result), it outputs a json object.
This is a pure JavaScript approach and you require a reasonably modern browser that supports parsing JSON into a native object.